# Kinesis Shards VS Partition Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

If at the time of creation of a Kinesis data stream I specify the number of shards to be let's say 10, and every time I put record I assign it a random Partition key like this:

```
 var putRecord = new PutRecord
            {
                Data = data ?? new byte[0],
                StreamName = stream,
                PartitionKey = GetRandomPartitionKey()
            };
```

How will kinesis decide to put a record in a certain shard, and what happens if the number of unique Partition keys is more than the number of shards?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hashing and modulo.

The Partition Key is **hashed** and then divided by the number of shards. The **modulo** of the division determines the shard to use. This way, the partition key always uses the same shard. If the number of shards is changed, then the allocation will be different.

This is a common method used in many systems. For example, the internal storage of Python dictionaries uses this method to assign storage for key/value pairs.

Comment: so you are saying that no matter how many different partition keys I use, the record will end up in one of the 10 shards?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you wish to process a particular group of records in sequential order, then assign them the same partition key. If order is totally unimportant, then a random partition key is good.